# see performance In-memory database redis to show data using jmeter

Tags: docker, redis, jmeter

I want to do a test to find out the performance of the in memory database redis using a load test scenario, from this test I want to see the results of Throughput, Latency, Resource utilization and Error Rate In-memory database redis using the Apache Jmeter tool.

I hope you can tell me how to do this test.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't support Redis out of the box. I'm not aware of any existing [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) which support Redis.

I can think of the following options:

1. Use [Redis JDBC Connector](https://www.cdata.com/kb/articles/redis-features.rst), it will allow you to go for [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler for running Redis queries
2. Use Redis Java client library like [Jedis](https://github.com/redis/jedis) from [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy). You can get example code snippets from [Redis Java Guide](https://redis.io/docs/connect/clients/java/)